# Problemas para obtener datos al convertir un campo int a decimal.

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo una tabla con dos campos, `nombre` y `cantidad de productos`, estoy generando un campo adicinal para ver la cantidad de productos que se consumen en 10 meses para eso estoy haciendo un `select` así:

```
select nombre, existencia , cast((cantidad/ 10) as decimal(6,2)) from productos
```

y tambien ...

```
select nombre, existencia , convert(decimal (6,2), (cantidad/ 10)) decimal from productos
```

el problema es que me arroja los datos enteros y no con decimales, por ejemplo así:

`175 / 10 : 17.0` en lugar de mostrármelo así `17.5` , donde `175` es `cantidad`. 
que me esta faltando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto pasa porque la conversión a decimal la debes hacer **antes** de la división.

Actualmente lo que está sucediendo es que tienes un dato `int`, que divides por 10, y eso te entrega como resultado una **división entera** (sin decimales), y después lo estás convirtiendo a decimal.

```
SELECT nombre, existencia , cast(cantidad as decimal(6,2))/10
from productos 
;
```